# Time Complexity - solving T(n) equations

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

i need some help with calculating time complexity.. 
this is the equations:

```
i) T(n) = 2T(n-1)-T(n-2)+5n+7
ii) T(n)=T(n-1)+logn
iii) T(n) = 2T(√n)+logn
```

my teacher tried to explain this but no one understand... i cant use the way of `n^logba` beacause of the B is 1... there is other way to solve those equations?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking if there is some method that is as easy as the Master Theorem is for problems of the form T(n) = aT(n/b)+n^d

As you mentioned, you cannot use the Master Theorem because there is no b

I am sorry to tell you, that you will not find a Method that is nice like the Master Theorem. You will have to follow it for a few steps and see if you can find a pattern. It won't be easy like problems in the form aT(n/b)+n^d